# JSON to String Decoding but not able to import and throwing Error

Tags: java, json, string, netbeans, decode

I am using Netbeans to write a code to decode JSON to String. I have added the following libraries json-simple-1.1.1 and json-20131018 JAR files.My code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class JSONDecode 
{
    public static void main(String str[])
    {
            String jsonString="{\"stat\": { \"sdr\": \"aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff\", \"rcv\": \"aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff\", \"time\": \"UTC in millis\", \"type\": 1, \"subt\": 1, \"argv\": [{\"type\": 1, \"val\":\"stackoverflow\"}]}}";
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONObject newjson=jsonObject.getJSONObject("stat");
            System.out.println(newjson.toString());
            jsonObject=new JSONObject(newjson.toString());
            System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("rcv"));
            System.out.println(newjson.toJSONArray("argv"));

    }
}
```

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - package org.json.simple does not exist
>         at coursera.JSONDecode.(JSONDecode.java:4)
>       Exception in thread "main" C:\Users\saish\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1
>       BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing the following libraries json-20131018 and json-simple-1.1.1 to the project buildpath does the work.